# real analysis countable, uncountable sets

Tags: analysis

Prove
If {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} are two sequences of zeros and ones, show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n}{2^n}$$ if and only if $x_n=y_n$ for all $n>1$ or if there is an integer $n$ such that either $x_n=1, y_n=0$ or $x_n=0,y_n=1$ for all $k>n$ and $x_k=y_k$ for all $k<n$.

I've been having a really tough time with this proof- any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ the two sides of the equation, and $P$ and $Q$ be the two propositions ($P$: $x_n=y_n$ for all $n>1$ , $Q$: "there is an integer...etc"). You must prove $A=B \implies P \cup Q$ and  $P  \implies A=B$ and  $Q \implies A=B$. Which part is hard for you?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that problem is asked in that way:

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two sequences with $x_n, y_n \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ for all $n$ and we are given that

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{10^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y_n}{10^n}$$

To find a relation between the sequences just consider these sums as "fractions". I mean, both sums represent real numbers in $[0,1]$ "in base $10$" so we have

$$ 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_n \dots = 0,y_1 y_2 y_3 \dots y_n \dots $$

Then how can you conclude a relation between $x_n$ and $y_n$ in such a case? I guess you say:

i) it can happen that $x_n = y_n$ for all $n$.

Or

ii) if $k$ is the minimum index such that $x_k \neq y_k$ then it must hold that either

$0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_k = 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots y_k 999 \dots \,$ or $\, 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_k 9 9 9 \dots = 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots y_k$

(This is just a kind of $0,5 = 0,4999999999999 \dots$ case)

Now return to your problem:

Your sums are in fact equal to "base 2" representation of real numbers in $[0,1]$ and hence

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y_n}{2^n}$$

can be considered $$ 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_n \dots = 0,y_1 y_2 y_3 \dots y_n \dots \quad \text{ in base } 2.$$

Now, what can you say about $x_n$ and $y_n$ in this "binary" case?

i) it can happen that $x_n = y_n$ for all $n$.

Or

ii) if $k$ is the minimum index such that $x_k \neq y_k$ then it must hold that either

$0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_k = 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots y_k 1 1 1 \dots \,$ or $\, 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots x_k 1 1 1 \dots = 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots y_k$

(This is just a kind of $0,1 = 0,0011111111 \dots$ case in base $2$)